# AWS lambda build FilterExpression using event

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, querystringparameter

I'm trying to build a FilterExpression to use in a scan function on DynamoDb table.

```
filter_expression = None
for k in event:
    print(k, ":", event[k])
    filter_expression = filter_expression & Key(k).eq(event[k])
```

I get the following error:
  "errorMessage": "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'Equals'",

How do I initialize the filter_expression variable so that I can use it to build the filter expression using the query string parameters? I've also tried to initialize it using the following:

```
filter_expression = {}
```

But then I get this error:
  "errorMessage": "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'dict' and 'Equals'",

Thank you for any help.